# Print specific elements on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to print specific text elements of a page. I currently have 10 cards on a single page and when a user chooses to print a specific card, I only want the chosen card to print. I was using `javascript:window.print()`, but found that it prints all the cards. However I found a snippet of code (below) that does what I want, but strips off the logo. I've try adding `document.getElementById('logo')` but it doesn't work. Not sure how to add the logo as a printable area as well. Is there a jQuery method as well that could handle this without using a plugin?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="logo" src="picture.jpg">
    <div class="card" id="card-a">Text <a href="" onclick="printDiv('card-a)">Print</a></div>
    <div class="card" id="card-b">Text <a href="" onclick="printDiv('card-b)">Print</a></div>
    <div class="card" id="card-c">Text <a href="" onclick="printDiv('card-c)">Print</a></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Comment: That solution you found is poor. It may "work" now, but it may break things later. What you should do is simply hide the content you don't want. I can't give an exact solution because I don't know if that's your entire page.

Comment: I did create a plugin to do this exact thing (fairly small with a lot of options) - https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Comment: @Jason, I did try your plugin (found a link to it on another post), but may have done something wrong, because the CSS wasn't being read. I'll give it another go and form a new question if I have any. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the HTML before you overwrite the body:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var logoContent = document.getElementById("logo").outerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = logoContent + printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Comment: I noticed none of the print styles (CSS) are being read. Is that possible?